# LoadRunner SMTP - Sends Email to BCC instead TO

Tags: jmeter, smtp, gmail, performance-testing, loadrunner

I am trying to send mail via STMP protocol using Loadrunner. I want the mail to be delivered as "TO" instead of "BCC".

Even I am using mail id in "TO" attribute but it is sending as "BCC".

Any solution will be appreciated.

**LR Script:**
[image: Loadrunner Script Code]

**Gmail Output:**
[image: Output from Gmail]

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: As an aside, claiming that you are Microsoft Outlook Express when you are clearly not is not buying you any new friends, and might upset some spam filters.

Comment: I'll take care going forward.

Comment: Better still would be to [edit] your question to replace the picture of code with actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be placing gmail under load.  Read both your user agreement for Gmail and your user agreement for LoadRunner.  Any system you are placing under load should be one you own, control, manage, or have permission from those who do.

These are dangerous tools, designed to take down systems.  You do not point them at third party software where you do not have permission

Comment: I am using gmail just to test few iteration, not for actual load test. I will be using specific test mail for volume testing. Any inputs on the issue which i  pasted

Comment: Move it to an internal mail system.  Spammers try to use these tools commonly to send out bulk email.   I cannot be party to a break in the Gmail and LoadRunner license agreements

Comment: This should probably be a comment rather than an answer.